# Nested operations in QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt

When creating item models, such as by subclassing `QAbstractItemModel`, are the basic operations like row insertion and removal intended to be *nested*?

In practice for example, must a call to `::beginInsertRows()` immediately followed by a call to `::endInsertRows()`? Or in contrast, is it allowed to call `::beginInsertRows()` twice with distinct arguments, then do the insertion and then call the corresponding `::endInsertRows()` twice?

I am wondering because when reading the `QAbstractItemModel` sources I [observed](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#n2601) that operations are done on a stack basis. Note the [`d->changes.push...`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#n2606) On the other hand, `d->changes` is not used anywhere else than in then `beginInsert/endInsert...` etc. pairs of functions.

Comment: I don't think you should use nested blocks on insertion/removal. One pair of beginInsertRows/endInsertRows is sufficient. You just need to use correct arguments to define the whole range of rows inserted/removed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I broke the insertion down so that I can first do the `beginInsertRows` / *insertion* / `endInsertRows` sequence for the parent items and then the `beginInsertRows` / *insertion* / `endInsertRows` sequence for child items.

It seemed to work out fine at first, but I had some very strange bugs when I used my custom model with a `QSortFilterProxyModel`. After quite a few hours of fixing tiny inconsistencies in my model and getting increasingly better (or just more sane) results, I was stuck with a last strange behavior, but ran out of ideas of where to look for errors on my part.

Then I thought I'd give a shot to another approach: one `beginInsertRows`, insert both the parents and their children and then one `endInsertRows`. To my surprise, it works very well. Finally I can tick this bloody model off my task list.

---

@vahancho, sorry for my previous comment. I was exhausted from trying to get my custom model to behave and misunderstood your question due to my impatience. Your comment actually holds the correct answer.